# MySQL: how many different customers ordered

Tags: mysql

i have a question with the data base Northwind
i need to Write a query that will retrieve for each Product the product name and how many different customers ordered it when the number of customers who ordered the same product must be at least 2, ie at least two different customers ordered the product

i did something like that but idk how to continue
thx

```
SELECT  p.ProductID,p.ProductName ,count(CustomerId)
FROM Products p  
join `order details` oon p.ProductID=o.ProductID AND Quantity>=2 
join Orders kk where kk.OrderID=o.OrderID
group by p.ProductID
order by p.ProductID
```

Comment: Is this a student assignment? The purpose of assignments is to solve them on your own - if you just get the answer you won't benefit from the learning and trying yourself.

Comment: SELECT  p.ProductID,p.ProductName ,count(CustomerId)
FROM Products p  join `order details` o
on p.ProductID=o.ProductID AND Quantity>=2 
join Orders kk where kk.OrderID=o.OrderID
group by p.ProductID
order by p.ProductID

Comment: and IVO i Practicing exercises and another problems , i just dont sure if i right

Comment: i did it , but i dont sure if my answer is good or not

Comment: What is `Quantity >= 2` for? The assignment says to count the number of customers who ordered it, that has nothing to do with the quantity that they ordered.

Comment: so which So which column do I need for that ? @Barmar

Comment: It's not in a column, it's the result of `COUNT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question says that the number of customers must be at least 2, not the quantity that they ordered. You can do this in a `HAVING` clause that compares the aggregate count.

You need to use `COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerId)` so you don't count the same customer multiple times for each order.

```
SELECT  p.ProductID,p.ProductName ,count(DISTINCT kk.CustomerId) AS numCustomers
FROM Products p  
join `order details` on p.ProductID=o.ProductID 
join Orders kk on kk.OrderID=o.OrderID
group by p.ProductID
order by p.ProductID
HAVING numCustomers >= 2
```